# Ругается валидация Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Контроллер:

```
 dump($request->data);
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'data' => 'mimes:doc,docx,txt',
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
       return redirect()->back()
          ->withErrors($validator)
           ->withInput();
  }
}
```

Форма:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/" method="post" >
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Имя</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{ old('name') }}" placeholder="Имя">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Отправка файла</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="file" name="data" >
                    <p class="help-block">Допустимы .txt,.doc,.docx</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Отправить</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Возвращает ошибку:

```
Поле data должно быть файлом одного из следующих типов: doc, docx, txt.
```

Делаю dump:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Глупейшая ошибка:
Забыл добавить

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```